# Iphone push notification issue

Tags: iphone, notifications, push

I am working on iphone push notification. I can able to get my device token. I am using .net for pushing json data. But the issue is i cant get the notification. I just want to know whether .net has to push json data over in hosted machine?

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is related to:

[Add iPhone push notification using ASP.NET server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142095/add-iphone-push-notification-using-asp-net-server)

Read through the linked project in there. It is pretty comprehensive. You can actually just use that library... it is pretty good.

Unless I misunderstood the question?

Comment: hi ginamin thanks for your response. I am using the code from http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/ but it says success on sending with proper device token and pem file. but the problem is it is not notified in my testing ipod touch.

Comment: You need to use the device token to identify which device the push will be sent to. The .pem file is your SSL key file. All this is used to create a stream with the apple push server. 

Push guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding... Your notification is properly formatted, but the device isn't receiving the push? That sounds like your device token isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use following snippet to send Push Notification

```html
 public void PendingNotification(string DeviceToken,string message)
    {
        try
        {
            int port = 2195;
            //Developer
            String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
            //Production
            //String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";
            String certificatePassword = "XXXXXXX";
            string certificatePath = Server.MapPath("~/cer.p12");
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), certificatePassword);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
            //String DeviceToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
            String LoginName = "Name";
            int Counter = 1; //Badge Count;  
            String Message = message;
            String UID = "your choice UID";
            string payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + Message + "\",\"badge\":" + Counter + ",\"sound\":\"default\"},\"UID\":\"" + UID + "\",\"LoginName\":\"" + LoginName + "\"}";
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            writer.Write((byte)0);
            writer.Write((byte)0);
            writer.Write((byte)32);
            writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(DeviceToken.ToUpper()));
            writer.Write((byte)0);
            writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
            byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            writer.Write(b1);
            writer.Flush();
            byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            sslStream.Write(array);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
            .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
            .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
            .ToArray();
    }
    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;
        Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);
        return false;
    }
```