# Send notification for iOS using .net or C#

Tags: c#, ios, .net

I want to send push notification on iOS device using C# or .net code. But I always failed to achieve this. Please refer best tutorial or code for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a broad question and since you have only asked for the tutorial links have a look at following:

[Add iPhone push notification using ASP.NET server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142095/add-iphone-push-notification-using-asp-net-server)

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: PushSharp hangs on start

Comment: @Toolkit Well that is definitely not a reason to down vote based on the context of question and answer.

Comment: you are advising a solution that is a waste of time? What else can be a reason to downvote?

Comment: @Toolkit I can't stop you from down voting and neither can I change your mind. But still PushSharp is a great library and it works fine. If you think there is an issue in their latest release you should raise a ticket on their github repo.

Answer (score -3):

In a purely .Net world you might well use a technology called SignalR for this - I would look and see if there are SignalR clients available for iOS. I would be surprised if there were not...